# how do i get git to show command-line help in windows?

Tags: git, msysgit

How do i get git to show command-line help in windows?

I'm using msysgit 1.7.4.

It's defaulting to open the html help in the browser.

I just want to show the text help on the console.

I've seen the config help.format (which is set to html by default).  I tried setting this to man or info, but it just says that:

```
fatal: no info viewer handled the request
```

Thanks,
matt

Answer (score 16):

Use `git <command> -h` instead of `--help` or `help`. It works in all recent versions of Git for Windows, but gives only the short usage, not the full description.

Answer (score 12):

<del>[Issue 187](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=187)</del> [issue 696](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/696) does report:

> The main problem is that **we do ship neither `man.exe` nor the man pages**.
>   Otherwise, you could set `help.format` to '`man`' in `/etc/gitconfig`.

So right now, this isn't possible...

As [jamiebarrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222090/jamiebarrow) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517564/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-command-line-help-in-windows/5517857#comment54615639_5517857):

> You could also try [installing man yourself](https://superuser.com/questions/295398/man-pages-for-git-bash-on-windows-7#comment919391_634889)

```
MinGW-get install msys-man.
```

> `man` is also [available as a windows binary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/):  (found via the [mingw FAQ](http://mingw.org/wiki/FAQ#toc10)). That page also has `groff`.

---

As mentioned in "[Getting Started - Getting Help](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Getting-Help)", those three commands invokes the man page, but only in its HTML version:

```
$ git help <verb>
$ git <verb> --help
$ man git-<verb>
```

`git <verb> -h` does not print the man page, only the short usage section (nothing to do with `man`)

Comment: Wow, that's really kind of unfortunate. That's the main way I learned to use it!

Comment: You could also try installing `man` yourself, see this SuperUser post: http://superuser.com/questions/295398/man-pages-for-git-bash-on-windows-7#comment919391_634889

Comment: The issue 187 link does not work anymore - but there is [similar report](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/696) in the github repo.

Comment: @Zitrax Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

I've just spent some time researching the subject, and these are my conclusions:

- msysgit ships with .html and .txt documentation, the latter being well suited for reading on the console; however, no option for directly displaying the txt exists. help.format only supports web/man/info
- there's no way to coax the 'web' format for that purpose - I tried renaming the .txt files to .html and setting my git web.browser to more (together with browser.more.cmd), only to find out that the windows implementation of Git ignores these settings and launches the html file directly (i.e. in the default browser): http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/10798
- unless you want to install and use cygwin, there's no easy way to use man or info either - you'll need to download a port of the executable, together with its dependencies (groff, etc), configure it, and download the manpages manually

In the end I resolved for the simplest approach:

githelp.bat:
@more "C:\Program Files\Git\doc\git\html\%1.txt"

githelpfind.bat:
@dir /b "C:\Program Files\Git\doc\git\html\*.txt" | find "%1"

Usage:

```
\> githelpfind prune
git-prune-packed.txt
git-prune.txt

\> githelp git-prune
(blah blah blah)
```

A little more typing this way, but a functional solution.

Comment: That there is no console output on Windows still kinda sux, but this is better than nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no .txt docs in the recent Git for Windows installations. Only .html.

Comment: There's always Lynx.  After some experimentation, I went with the latest stable slang version of Lynx - go [here](https://invisible-island.net/lynx/#http_install) and pick Stable release/slang.  I needed to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Lynx - web browser` to my path and execute `git config --global web.browser lynx`.  This will probably satisfy my needs - if it works for anyone else, I'll re-post this as an answer.