# git help in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, git, cmd, windows-console

The `git help` command on Windows (`msysgit` distribution) spawns web browser each time I run it. I tried `git help -m` which reports `"No manual entry for ..."` and `git help -i` which says `"info: Terminal type 'msys' is not smart enough to run Info."` The same happens in `bash` under `Cygwin`.

Is there any sensible way to get light-weight help in `cmd` terminal?

Comment: You can install git and man using MSYS2 with `pacman -S git man`. After the installation is complete, you can run the command which depend on `man`, e.g. `git init --help`. After add `C:\msys64\usr\bin` to `PATH` it will be even more convenient, you will be able to run it with `powershell` or `cmd` like builtin command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for Git 2.x (June 2017, Git 2.13.1)

You still don't have man:

```
> git -c help.format=man help add
warning: failed to exec 'man': No such file or directory
fatal: no man viewer handled the request
```

Same for `git <verb> --help`.
`git <verb> -h` does not print the man page, only the short usage section (nothing to do with man)

---

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), when `git cmd -h` shows more than one line of usage text (e.g. the cmd subcommand may take sub-sub-command), parse-options API learned to align these lines, even across [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)/[l10n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation).

See [commit 4631cfc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4631cfc20bd446bbacb078891389f58faeb13bcb) (21 Sep 2021), and [commit 84122ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84122ecdbfdf5a52153a34b53fad60a5f50e6b13), [commit 78a5091](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78a509190dcac5a3f9971b35c1962c1eeee6af27), [commit 5d70198](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d70198efedcbb2bf626a5d007d8080cd342cb6e) (13 Sep 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d7bc852](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7bc8521518d4821c5d2e18742991a6ad05efee1), 13 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`parse-options`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4631cfc20bd446bbacb078891389f58faeb13bcb): properly align continued usage output
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Some commands such as "[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4631cfc20bd446bbacb078891389f58faeb13bcb/Documentation/git-stash.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> emit continued options output with e.g. `git stash -h`, because `usage_with_options_internal()` prefixes with its own whitespace the resulting output wasn't properly aligned.
> Let's account for the added whitespace, which properly aligns the output.
>
> The "`git stash`" command has usage output with a N_() translation that legitimately stretches across multiple lines;
>
> ```
> N_("git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]\n"
>    "          [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]\n"
> [...]
> ```
>
> We'd like to have that output aligned with the length of the initial "`git stash`" output, but since `usage_with_options_internal()` adds its own whitespace prefixing we fell short, before this change we'd emit:
>
> ```
> $ git stash -h
> usage: git stash list [<options>]
>    or: git stash show [<options>] [<stash>]
>    [...]
>    or: git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
>           [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]
>           [...]
> ```
>
> Now we'll properly emit aligned output.
> I.e.
> the last four lines above will instead be (a whitespace-only change to the above):
>
> ```
> [...]
> or: git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
>               [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]
>               [...]
> ```
>
> This change is relatively more complex since I've accounted for making it future-proof for RTL translation support.
> Later in `usage_with_options_internal()` we have some existing padding code dating back to [d7a38c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7a38c54a6ccbcbcf29d8cf1110b2702c8b3f7f8) ("`parse-options`: be able to generate usages automatically", 2007-10-15, Git v1.5.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d66dc9657f195cb241387a87bcdd5709abd8a21)) which isn't RTL-safe, but that code would be easy to fix.
> Let's not introduce new RTL translation problems here.

---

Original answer (2014)

No, even though an alternative, based on a 'cat' of the htlp txt files, is suggested in "[how do I get git to show command-line help in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993124/6309)".

There [`man.<tool>.cmd` config](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/source/detail?r=a26a06afed783cb7cf7207c1bcb2d1781d623d1e&name=mmap&repo=4msysgit&path=/help.c) introduced in 2008, allows to set a custom command, but msys shell isn't shipped with `man.exe`.

Comment: Not only man.exe is absent, man pages are also absent in Git 2.13.1.

Answer (score 14):

It works for particular commands: `git <command> -h`

**Edit**, thanks to @the-happy-hippo

But it shows only a brief description, not the full one, as `git help <command>` or `git <command> --help` gives on Windows.

Comment: yes, this shows short help, but not full man page with extended description, examples, etc. (e.g., compare the output of `git help add -m` to `git help add`).

Comment: edited, thank for clarifiiction. Not really sure about your example, the former tries to give man help, but fails due to no man on my Windows (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517857/2007631), the latter gives just html help..

Comment: Useful to know that -h gives you the short help.

Answer (score 9):

**`git <verb> -h`** shows a command usage in the same **terminal window**.

On the other hand, `git <verb> --help` and `git help <verb>` open a browser.

Answer (score -1):

World's most overengineered workaround for this problem: use WSL

(that is, unless you already are a WSL user, in which case it's merely an ordinary workaround)

1. Install one of the linux distros via Windows Store
2. Go in and ensure it has the git package installed
3. From the Windows command line, `bash -c 'git help fetch'` etc.

Here's an alias for that last one:

```
[alias]
    hep = "!f() { $SYSTEMROOT/System32/bash -c \"git help $1\"; }; f"
```

(And no you can't [override git built-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias), but you can make a shell command to intercept and reroute `help`.)