# Git Bash "help" commands but prevent usage of browser

Tags: git, bash

I want to do `git log --help` but I don't want the annoying "browser" to pop up. I just want the syntax listing right within Bash.  Like when i type `git -?`, I get:

```
Unknown option: -? usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

but when I type `git log -?`, I get:

```
fatal: unrecognized argument: -?
```

The moment I use the `--help` parameter, it spawns my web browser.  I just want the syntax spec listed right within Bash.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Personally, I find the inline Bash help listings easier to read and comprehend than the web based help.

Comment: it seems an uncommon behavior. you can try `man git log`

Comment: @xaa I believe there needs to be a dash between `git` and `log`, otherwise `man` is going to first open the `git` man page, and then the help for `builtin`, because apparently `man log` brings up the help for `logout`, which falls back to the `builtin`s help.

Comment: What platform is this ? It sounds like you are using Git with bash on Windows in Msys or a similar distribution.

Comment: Do you have the `help.format` global setting set to `web`? You can check with `git config -l`. If it is `web`, you might want to change it to `man`, see [git help documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help).

Comment: yes i am using msys (mingw64) on windows.  and current help.format is set to html.

Answer (score 2):

The git setting `help.format` needs to be set to something else than `html`, but your environment needs to support the alternatives.

You can try without changing the config by [adding a parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help#Documentation/git-help.txt---man):

`git log --help --man` uses the man tool, if present.

See [git help in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154279/git-help-in-windows-command-prompt) for Windows CMD, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just to print the output to the standard output instead of spawning a viewer, you can use:

```
git log --help | cat
```

You could also try less, that brings some added features:

```
git log --help | less
```