# The Git help command keeps opening VLC media player

Tags: git, git-bash, vlc, windows-11

I recently installed Git on my new Windows 11 laptop. I tested out standard commands to make it's working, but "git  --help" or any version for requesting manual pages on a command cause my VLC media player to open and nothing plays. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I googled Git AND VLC media player and this doesn't seem to be a common issue. I tried resetting the preferences on the media player but it still keeps opening.

Comment: Sounds like you've somehow associated man pages (or whatever the Windows equivalent is) with VLC. Check out this article ~ https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/check-reset-file-associations-windows/

Comment: The html files should at the moment be configured to be opened by vlc instead of your web browser. Change that and it should be OK...

Comment: @Phil Thank you for the article it helped my understanding.

Comment: @Philippe per your advice I managed to do just that, but I was looking to be able to open the man pages in the Git bash window if that's possible.

Comment: "*I was looking to be able to open the man pages in the Git bash window*" [Seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517857/7976758) this isn't possible. But see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23154409/7976758

Answer (score 1):

If changing the HTML association is somehow tricky in your environment, you can force the use of a browser with some [Git configuration settings](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-helpbrowser).

You can test those configuration with:

```
git -c help.browser=firefox -c browser.firefox.path=C:\path\to\firefox.exe -c help.format=web help switch
```